# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas'

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

How can I resolve this issue?
I have installed the bootstrap, I have also installed the bootstrap react-bootstrap.
but still, it is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5765

Answer (score 0):

**Just import this 2 files**

1. Add bootstrap by `npm install bootstrap`
2. in `App.js` imports css and js

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "bootstrap"; // <-- JS File
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the following code:

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next
```